# Android Material Design SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

I'm trying to implement a SearchView with the Material Design styles: http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/search.html#search-in-app-search but I can't find a control which looks like the Material Design one. I want to implement a SearchView like the google play or gmail app one. Any idea?

Comment: I'm only aware of [this one](https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch), but haven't gotten around to trying it out yet. Looks promising enough though and may provide all the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Thank @MH. it looks really promising, but I'm looking for a native solution (without third party libraries). Anyway, if I can't find a native solution, I'll try this library. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Well, I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but your requirement means you can stop your search right now, as there are no 'native' (or Google-provided) alternatives at this stage. They might have one in the pipeline, but I suppose only time will be able to tell. Until then, you'll have two choices: use libraries that *are* available, or reinvent the wheel (if you think you can do a better job). Anyways, good look with the hunt!

Comment: Thanks for the information @MH. I think I'll take a look at the PersistentSearch library.

Comment: Just thought it might be worth mentioning: I ran into [this alternative today](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview). Again, haven't tried it (yet), but appears to solve the same problem.

Comment: Thanks @MH. I'm trying both and I'll tell you about it.

Comment: Finally, I have chosen this library: https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview it's very flexible, customisable and very easy to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library

https://github.com/lapism/SearchView

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.lapism:searchview:2.1.1'
        }
```